# Contract not deploying with web3

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-deployment, dapps

I'm writing a web-based DApp with web3, and am trying to get my JavaScript to deploy a contract.

I've set up the abi, contract, and bytecode as follows:

```
const trade_abi = [ ... not shown: ABI copied from Remix ...
const trade_contract = web3.eth.contract(trade_abi);
const trade_bytecode = ... not shown: Bytecode copied from Remix
```

I am trying to deploy the contract `ValuED_trade`, which is in Solidity 0.5.1 and has the following consrtuctor:

```
    constructor(address parent_, uint24 ID_, int16 max, int16 price_, string memory content, string memory time) public{

        proposer = msg.sender;
        parent = ValuED(parent_);
        ID = ID_;
        max_seeking = max;
        price = price_;
        proposal_content = content;
        creation_time_ = time;
    }
```

I then try to create an instance of the contract as follows:

```
trade_contract.new(
  contract_address, 
  id_, 
  max, 
  amt_offered, 
  reason, 
  (new Date(Date.now())).toString(), 
  {
    from: user.account, 
    gas:840000000, 
    data:trade_bytecode
  }, 
  function(error, result){
    if(error) {
      alert("Error: Was not able to create a contract for this trade :(")
      console.log(error)
    }
    else {
      do_stuff(result) 
    }
})
```

This resulted in the following error:

```
MetaMask - RPC Error: Internal JSON-RPC error. 
{code: -32603, message: "Internal JSON-RPC error.", data: {…}, stack: "Error: Error: [ethjs-rpc] rpc error with payload {…method":"eth_sendRawTransaction"} [object Object]"}
```

I'm running this on a private blockchain with geth 1.9.3-stable.

Can anyone help me get this working?

Answer (score 0):

[To create a new contract instance](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.1/web3-eth-contract.html#eth-contract) pay attention to the uppercase c letter: `.Contract()` not `.contract()`.
`new web3.eth.Contract(jsonInterface[, address][, options])`